# C++ в современном мире

Tags: c++

В современное время, как правило, выделяют три "мейнстримовых" языка: C#, Java и C++.
(ну, допустим, что это так хотя бы в контексте данного поста ). Собственно, С# "вытек" из-за Java, а Java пришел на смену C\C++, упрощая разработку и привнося почти абсолютную кроссплатформенность. Java и C# - такие языки, что им нравится обучаться, реально ощущая их мощь, актуальность и спектр, где их можно задействовать.

Что же касается C++. Несомненно, этот язык занимает заслуженное место в топе "мэйнстримовых" языков и используется повсеместно. Тем не менее, изучая этот язык, можно довольно быстро заскучать начинающим: они видят, как использовать те же STL контейнеры, узнают об указателях и , возможно, даже о библиотеке Boost, но где все это реально можно применить( наверное, кроме олимпиад ), они могут недопонять.

C++ широко используется в научных разработках, биоинженерии, генетике, космонавтике( так, софт луноходов-марсоходов писан на СИ ) и т.д.

**Собственно, вопрос такой:**
Может быть изначально стоит лишь ознакомиться с C++, затем бросить его в "отдаленный уголок" мозга и продолжить изучать тот же Java или C#, четко зная, как и где их можно "круто" применить? А в будущем, если это потребуется, добраться до того "отдаленного участка" мозга, развернуть те "C++ крошки" и уже на их основе обучаться далее C++, но уже на практике?

Почему, изучая плюсы в одиночку( вне команды людей и вне интересной практики ), он кажется таким скучным, будто бы он создан только для программирования спутников и луноходов?

Comment: @Qsixs - хотите учить - учите, не хотите - не учите. Определитесь с целями и двигайтесь в их сторону.

> он кажется таким скучным, будто бы он создан только для программирования спутников и луноходов?

потому что не определились с целями.

И да, многие авторы, которые пишут о с++ хотят рассказать о том, как он отлично может эффективно делать разные вещи. А многих нужно пара кнопок в окне и в продакшн.

Comment: Никуда c# не вытек. Для каждой задачи нужно использовать подходящий инструмент.

Comment: >Никуда c# не вытек.

почему же? В общем-то никогда не скрывалось, что при разработке C# во  многом опирались на Java (что заметно невооруженным глазом), да и появился он после отказа Microsoft от собственной реализации JVM и судебных исков со стороны Sun

Comment: @DreamChild, перечитайте топикстартера, там "из-за", а не "из".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С++ - это всего лишь один из огромного множества языков программирования. Не лучше и не хуже других (разумеется, чем-то лучше, чем-то хуже, не суть). Поэтому нельзя говорить, что он прям обязателен к изучению. Это всего лишь один из  инструментов работы программиста. Нужно ли изучать каждый отдельно взятый язык обычно зависит от области деятельности, которой программист хочет себя посвятить. То есть первична должна быть задача, под которую выбирается язык, а не язык, под который подбираются задачи. Учить язык только ради того, что это С++ вряд ли разумно.

Что же касается того, "почему  он кажется таким скучным" - так язык и не должен никого развлекать. Он должен выполнять возложенные на него задачи (в частности, от С++ требуется сохранение высокой производительности и средств низкоуровнего программирования вместе с наличием высокоуровневых абстракций).
 Более того, C#/Java/etc тоже ведь вроде не жонглируют горящими топорами, не рассказывают анекдотов и не пропукивают лезгинку в угоду развлечению пользователя. Вряд ли от промышленного языка программирования разумно требовать  того, чтобы он был еще и интересным (субъективное свойство кстати - ведь довольно сложно сказать, что делает язык "интересным")

Comment: @DreamChild, откровенно говоря, идея, что можно выбрать язык под задачу, *не изучив его*, выглядит довольно сомнительной.

IMHO это все-таки "две стороны одной медали". 

Чем больше языков знает программист, тем более широкий спектр задач он сможет эффективно решать.

--

Что же касается конкретного вопроса ТС, то мне кажется (судя по стилю вопроса), что изучать ему кресты не стоит (ознакомиться, книжку-другую прочесть -- да, а глубоко нырять -- нет). 

А вот Си как следует изучить, не помешает.

Comment: @avp я, возможно, не совсем точно выразился. Разумеется, я не призываю на каждую конкретную задачу учить новый язык. Речь о том, что если человек хочет посвятить себя веб-разработке, то ему стоит учить язык А, либо язык Б, но не стоит учить язык В. Если он хочет заниматься системным программированием, то языки А и Б ему не помогут, а вот В - в самый раз.  Ну и так далее в том же духе. 

А в общем и целом я имел в виду, что С++ - такой же как и все прочие язык, со своей спецификой, но не "священная корова", он не обязателен к изучению и не имеет какого-то особого волшебного статуса

Answer (score -1):

https://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/cbuilder

*Если вы используете C++Builder XE6 для разработки приложений на стандартном С++ для различных устройств, вы сможете создавать «нативные» приложения для ПК, планшетов, смартфонов и даже носимых гаджетов типа Google Glass на основе единого исходного кода в рекордные сроки. Нужно быстродействие? С помощью C++Builder вы создаёте действительно «нативные» приложения, которые исполняются максимально быстро прямо на CPU устройства, а не на основе скриптов или виртуальной машины. Ваши приложения получат полный доступ к возможностям платформы, обеспечивая высочайший уровень пользовательского взаимодействия.*

Отрывок из рекламы с++ билдера))) Намёк на то, что Java и C# - отстой)))

Comment: я думал, верить релкаме как-то немодно уже

Comment: @sitev_ru: Вы действительно считаете, что C# и Java выполняются на виртуальной машине? У меня для вас есть новости.

Comment: Я думаю, что в данном случае реклама не врёт. Пишешь программу один раз и потом компилишь её под айфон или под андроид или под винду.

"Вы действительно считаете, что C# и Java выполняются на виртуальной машине?" ... думал, что это так... разве нет?

Comment: @sitev_ru расскажите пожалуйста, сколько программ под андроид, а

Comment: @sitev_ru: [Нет](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), конечно. Кто вам такое рассказал?